# Keep web server working after returning output to client (in php)

Tags: php

I am having a PHP web page which has a button. Whenever the user click this button, an AJAX request is sent to the server, and an email is sent back to him. A notification is also displayed on the screen. (It's similar to commenting on Facebook, the message is displayed, while the server keeps working to send emails).

Since sending email takes time, I want the server to return the output to the user first, then keeps working to send email.

Anyone knows how to achieve this in PHP? Thanks.

Comment: Since PHP's threading support is sketchy at best, the best thing to do is to put the email stuff into another php script and run it in the background using this method: http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2007/01/12/running-a-background-process-in-php/

Comment: @waitinforatrain: "sketchy at best" - tell me more - I didn't know PHP had *any* support for threads.

Comment: @symcbean, there's an pecl package that's semi-abandoned, pcntl_fork() which forks the process (though isn't threading can be used for similar) and some version of php_threading are floating around

Comment: @waitinfortrain, nope, still got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Really this is the same question as [I am running through a php background process problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203453/i-am-running-through-a-php-background-process-problem/7204846#7204846)

And as per my answer there, if the email is taking a long time to process then there's something wrong with your MTA config.

But assuming that might be something you can't fix, you might consider sending the email using a callback invoked via [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)() after your code does an explicit exit;

Comment: Hi symcbean, however, the program still needs to wait for all functions registered by register_shutdown_function(), doesn't it? Then it's still delayed.

Comment: Yes you can't process data without a thread running. But the browser isn't kept waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an email from php shouldn't take very long, since all it has to do is send a message to the mailserver, which can take it's time sending the email after.

However, to answer your question, you can execute another php script as a background process, and have that script send the email. On a linux box it's as easy as:

```
exec('php phpscript.php > /dev/null &');
```

Which will execute `phpscript.php` as a background process, so that your current script won't wait for it to finish. If you want you can redirect the output somewhere other than /dev/null so you can actually view the output later.

You might need to use `php-cli` instead of `php`. Depending on how your server is set up.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'll try this. By the way, I've found PHP function header(). If I want to redirect the user to another location, can I use this function? And leave sending email code after calling this function.

Comment: You can't send the user to a different page using a redirect response to an ajax request.